# Bigquery how to filter tables in dataset during List operation

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

Is there any way to search or filter for particular Table from Dataset using Table name while calling List operation? I understand that  documentation mentions use of Labels to filter Tables but in my case this will not suffice as  there is no restriction on number of Tables that can be created under a Dataset with or without Label . I am using Node library for my operations.

Comment: Not out of the box, no. You'll need to parse the results. Using the CLI tool you could use some bash and do it easily enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefered way to search or filter for particular Table (or any other metadata object) is to query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`. There are multiple `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables which could be used - `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_OPTIONS`, `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` etc.
More info at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables