# Bigquery how to filter tables and view during List operation

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery

Is there any way or node module api by which we can filter on views and tables while performing list operation.While doing list operation , we have response coming for both view and tables in the response.

Answer (score 0):

Let's have a look for the official documentation and [getTables()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigquery/latest/Dataset.html#getTables) function, which allows you for lists tables in specified dataset. Before using you need to change `datasetId` variable:

```
function main(datasetId = 'my_dataset') {
  const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
  const bigquery = new BigQuery();

  async function listTables() {
    const datasetId = 'my_dataset';

    // List all tables in the dataset
    const [tables] = await bigquery.dataset(datasetId).getTables();

    console.log('Tables:');
    tables.forEach(table => console.log(table.id));
  }
  listTables();
}

main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

Additionally, please find another example with retrieving the view [here](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigquery/blob/6438df629e9adb707338bd53959c7c10e0ae2936/samples/getView.js). On the other hand you can achieve that by querying the metadata per dataset, which has more options to filter or search like tables within the dataset. Refer to the following [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62755263/bigquery-how-to-filter-tables-in-dataset-during-list-operation).